# How can I create a site on the tor network? PHP

Tags: onion-routing, ubuntu

I programmed on my PC a website in php using xampp and mysql server, but how do I send these files contained in my folder, which is located at:
(ex: htdocs/my finished site),
to the tor network?

Answer (score 0):

You should point the address:port of you webserver to Tor.

First, create a folder in which the files for the .onion domain will be put on:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tor/<site_name>
```

Change the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 0700 /var/lib/tor/
```

Change the folder ownership to user running Tor (in Debian is debian-tor):

```
sudo chown -R debian-tor:debian-tor /var/lib/tor/
```

Edit your /etc/tor/torrc file and insert these lines

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/<site_name>
HiddenServicePort 80 <webserver_address>:<port>
```

Replace <webserver_address>: with the address:port of the webserver, for example 127.0.0.1:8080

Restart Tor:

```
sudo systemctl restart tor.service
```

And finally pick up the address of your hidden site:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/tor/<site_name>/hostname
```

(Sorry if my English is bad).

Comment: basically it is, **but the PHP itself needs to be secured to prevent any data leaks**!

Comment: Yep. There is a lot of tutorials about this just searching in Google..